# What's the difference between repartition() vs spark.sql.shuffle.partitions

Tags: apache-spark

What happens when we repartition data to higher number than spark.sql.shuffle.partitions property? Are these related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which variant of Dataset.repartition you will call.

If you call `repartition(partitionExprs: Column*): Dataset[T]` - in this case number of partitions will be based on **spark.sql.shuffle.partitions** parameter.

If you call `repartition(numPartitions: Int): Dataset[T]` - in this case number of partitions will be based on **numPartitions** passed parameter.

Comment: Does that mean in the 2nd case we can end up in large number of partitions which could result in performance bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, you can end up in large number of partitions, but would it be performance bottleneck or not depends on many factors like cluster configuration, job configuration, dataset size etc. 
But don't forget that repartition will redistribute data across nodes it means a lot of shuffles. If you need to contract number of partitions you can look at ```def coalesce(numPartitions: Int): Dataset[T] ``` on Dataset.